# How to change the AWS node client user agent?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I'm using the node `aws-sdk` package and I need to send a custom user agent in the S3 requests in order to identify the process in the console log.

I've seen a method to do this in the Java SDK but I can't see any similar in the node package.

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After browsing in the source code I found an undocumented option to set the user agent: `customUserAgent`

```
const options = { customUserAgent: 'my-process-name' };
const client  = new AWS.S3(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an agent in the `httpoptions` field of the `options` you send to the constructor as per [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor-property):

> httpOptions (map) — A set of options to pass to the low-level HTTP request.
>
> Currently supported options are:
>
> - proxy [String] — the URL to proxy requests through
> - agent [http.Agent, https.Agent] — the Agent object to perform HTTP requests with. Used for connection pooling. Defaults to the global agent (http.globalAgent) for non-SSL connections. Note that for SSL connections, a special Agent object is used in order to enable peer certificate verification. This feature is only available in the Node.js environment.
> - connectTimeout [Integer] — Sets the socket to timeout after failing to establish a connection with the server after connectTimeout milliseconds. This timeout has no effect once a socket connection has been established.
> - timeout [Integer] — Sets the socket to timeout after timeout milliseconds of inactivity on the socket. Defaults to two minutes (120000).
> - xhrAsync [Boolean] — Whether the SDK will send asynchronous HTTP requests. Used in the browser environment only. Set to false to send requests synchronously. Defaults to true (async on).

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas! I had already seen these options but I couldn't get the user agent modified... Finally I found the right option `customUserAgent`